# Problem based on Cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function

I have been given the following cumulative distribution function. I need to compute the probability $P(1\leq X<2)$:

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x<0 \\[1ex] 
\frac{x^2}{10} & \text{ if } 0\leq x< 1 \\[1ex] 
\frac{x+2}{8} & \text{ if } 1\leq x< 2 \\[1ex] 
\frac{c(6x-x^2-1)}{2} & \text{ if } 2\leq x< 3 \\[1ex] 
1 & \text{ if } x\geq 3 
\end{cases}$$

For this problem, We  need to compute this probability $P(1\leq X<2)$ and also after looking at the CDF, we notice that the value of c is unknown. So, we might compute that here but if we look at the probability of interest here which is $P(1\leq X<2)$, it does not depend on that region for which CDF is unknown. So, we may proceed like this:

$$P(1\leq X<2) = F(2-) - F(1-) = \frac{4}{8} - \frac{1}{10} = \frac{16}{40}$$

Hence, this would be the answer.

I was just wondering if in the case this probability was dependent upon $c$, and then we would need to compute it. Then, How we may proceed?

We may get the mass (at the point of left discontinuity) and PDF (otherwise) and then sum or integrate that and hence we get the value of $c$. We know that point 0 and 1 are points of left discontinuity and may get the mass but what about 2 and 3 because to know that we would need the value of $c$.

Is there any other approach that we may follow to get the value of $c$? Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since $c$ does not affect the probability of any event contained in $(-\infty, 2),$ you don't need to find $c.$

Comment: This I am already aware of if you read my question, I have also stated that we don't need c for this specific problem but I was just wondering how would one can go about obtaining c in general.

Comment: Why, then, did you even ask about $\Pr(1\le X\lt 2)$?  It's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I never mentioned in my problem that I am having difficulty in calculating this probability. I have only asked about some probable ways of getting c in cases where my probability might depend on support where computing c might become necessary unlike in this case where i could just compute probability without the knowledge of c.

Answer (score 2):

My initial comment was

> There is a whole range of values of $c$ for which this function $F$ is
> a cdf. But given that $F$ is uniquely defined over $[0,2)$, they do
> not impact $\mathbb P(1\le X<2)$.

However, when looking at this definition of $F$,
$$\lim_{x\mapsto 1^-} F(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\mapsto 1^+} F(x)=\frac{3}{8}\,.$$
This function $F$ is thus decreasing at $1$ and cannot be a cdf. (Meaning there is a typo in its definition. *Since you wrote $F(1^-)=1/10$, is the denominator $10$ rather than $2$ over $(0,1)$?*)

Comment: Yes, there is typo. It was indeed $\frac{1}{10}$ Thanks for pointng it out. I have fixed that